# How can I render Partial views in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, partial

I have some data in `ViewData.Model`, and in my views I want to write a partial view and to pass their current model I have in my page.

How I can pass their current `ViewData.Model` and render them through the location of partials?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Create your partial view something like:

```
@model YourModelType
<div>
  <!-- HTML to render your object -->
</div>
```

Then in your view use:

```
@Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName", Model)
```

If you do not want a strongly typed partial view remove the `@model YourModelType` from the top of the partial view and it will default to a `dynamic` type.

**Update**

The default view engine will search for partial views in the same folder as the view calling the partial and then in the ~/Views/Shared folder.  If your partial is located in a different folder then you need to use the full path. Note the use of `~/` in the path below.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/SeachResult.cshtml", Model)
```

Comment: hi i my case container view is binded with "ContainerModel" and the partial view is in shared folder and is binded with "ChildrenModel" in @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/SeachResult.cshtml", Model) it is giving exception that "ChildrenModel is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level" can you suggest what to do??

Comment: And why is `@Html.RenderPartial(string viewName)` for ..? It always gives an error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'`.

Comment: @shashwat - use RenderPartial inside brackets to avoid that error.

Comment: e.g. @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ContactForm", Model); }

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= Html.Partial("PartialName", Model) %>
```

Comment: it's not worked in MVC 3. if i pass the location of partial in partialname that they not worked and give me error that @Html.RenderPartial(Globals.Theme_Path+"views/partials/seachresult.cshtml",ViewData.Model)

Comment: @Moby It looks like the partial view cannot be found, see my answer, but can you post the error message and then we maybe able to help further.

Comment: You shouldn't apply themes by using different views. Themes should be applied by using different images/css files. Also, you should use Partial and not RenderPartial.