# Confusion over relatively calling partial view in asp.net mvc 3 razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My app has  the following structure for views...

form related views

- views/form/datecontrol.cshtml
- views/form/textcontrol.cshtml
- views/form/checkboxcontrol.cshtml

...etc
and

search related views

- views/search/searchgrid.cshtml

now,in searchgrid.cshtml, I want to make a partial call to the controls under form. 
I tried all of the following but it still throws up an error.

```
@Html.Partial("~/form/textcontrol",
@Html.Partial("/form/textcontrol",
@Html.Partial("views/form/textcontrol",
```

How do i go about with this ?

Answer (score 3):

Put the shared views in the "Shared" folder, and then reference them as you would any other partial:

```
@Html.Partial("textcontrol")
```

If they must be in some other folder, try (be sure to include the ~/):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/form/textcontrol.cshtml")
```

[how i can render Partial views in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441615/how-i-can-render-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: thanks, but is that a must ? is it not possible to make a partial call to view under some other folder structure using html.partial?

Comment: edited to expand on an answer closer to what you want - try that