# Create view and partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3. I have a task to create a page that shows a list of data. ie I created a controller "Employee", then 1 view "Employee" which was renamed from Index and a partial view "EmployeeList".

The Partial View is used for listing the Employees in a Grid.

I need to render this partial view from the View, on a click or load . How ?

Comment: Did you even bother to search for a solution? possible duplicate of [how i can render Partial views in asp.net mvc 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441615/how-i-can-render-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 1):

To render a partial view within another view:

```
@Html.Partial("EmployeeList")
```

To pass in a specific model to the view:

```
@Html.Partial("EmployeeList", Model.EmployeeListModel)
```